# Why are Chrome performance.memory and the memory in Chrome devtools different?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory, heap-memory, performance-testing

The memory I found by `window.performance.memory` is larger then memory in devtools:

[image]

I'm doing some optimization of memory, I want to use a accurate value to show it.

What's their diffierence?